# Is it possible to export specific components of a .blend file?

Tags: export, blend-files

Let's say I've made a nice rig, but it relies on a Python script I made. I prepare a .blend file to distribute: I put all of the objects into a group and a store the script with a conspicuous name.

In order for some unwitting user to use my rig in one of their files, they must use the Append function once to import the group (.blend → Groups → [group]), and once more to import my script (.blend → Text → [script]).

While it's only a mild annoyance for those who know what they're doing, inexperienced users often get confused with this, especially with extra clutter whilst Appending (*Scene? Node Tree? Brush? FreestyleLineStyle?*).

Is it possible by any means to export specifically the components I'd like a user to import, like *specifically* this group and *specifically* this text and nothing else from the file?

Ideally, opening the resulting export would import the chosen components, eliminating the need to Append at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create one new "partial" file, and import into it only (eg) armatures, from your "complete" file and share that "partial" , of course.

Or create a copy of the "complete" file and delete everything except (eg) armatures. There is no "export only (eg) armatures" command.

Comment: That's unfortunate, you've still got the unavoidable Materials, Scene, etc. folders... Well, it's the best option we have for now.